# getting confused about metastability

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

I have read in few textbooks and online sources about metastabiliy and they claim that it rises from the first order phase transition, however the diagram clearly show that the second derivation of the free energy changes which means we should look for a saddle point in the curve. And this is the definition of second order phase transition!! Where is my mistake?[image]